Proof that $Z = \frac{X}{Y}$ follows Cauchy distribution if X and Y are independent $N(0,1)$
In the book I am currently reading the statement in the title is proved by starting with:
$$F_Z(z) = Pr(X/Y < z) = Pr(X-zY, Y>0) + Pr(X-zY > 0, Y<0)$$
Then double integrals are used and the CDF is derived wrt $z$. And indeed the PDF is the same as Cauchy. To train my rusty calculus skills, I tried to prove the same thing with Jacobian determinant, which was succesful. Now I am looking at the convolution formula:
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) \, dx$$
And I am wondering, whether that would also work to prove it, since $X-zY$ looks somehow tempting to plug in, but I am not sure how to start, since we still must consider whether $Y>0$ or $Y<0$. ChatGPT tells me it's too tedious to do that, but maybe you know better?

That convolution formula is valid for $Z=X+Y$, not $Z=X/Y$

So no chance the case X-zY, whereas when z=-1 would be X+Y, could be handled with that one?

This is a question that is best solved by sketching the $x$-$y$ plane and drawing on it a circle centered on the origin and a line $y = zx$ where $z$ is a *fixed positive real number.  Then, indicate by cross-hatching the region where $\frac yx \leq z$. Now, $F_Z(z) = P(\frac YX \leq z)$ is the total volume under the pdf surface in the indicated region, and because of the circular symmetry of the joint pdf, can be written down  in terms of $\arctan z$, no need for formal integration. Repeat (with a fresh sketch) for $z <0$. Then, differentiate the Cdf of $Z$ to get the pdf.

Actually, you will need a multiplicative analog of the convolution formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation for example).

First of all assume that $X,Y$ are continuous variables with density $f_X,f_Y$ and cdf $F_X,F_Y$, then $$\mathbb P[X/Y<z]=\mathbb P[\{X<zY \textrm{ and } Y\geq0\}\cup\{X>zY\textrm{ and } Y<0\}]=\int\int_{x<zy, y\geq0}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+\int\int_{x>zy, y<0}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_Y(y)\int_{-\infty}^{zy}f_X(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+\int_{-\infty}^0f_Y(y)\int_{zy}^\infty f_X(x)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=\int_{0}^\infty f_Y(y)F_X(zy)\mathrm dy+\int_{-\infty}^0 f_Y(y)(1-F_X(zy))\mathrm dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)F_X(zy)\mathrm{sign}(y)\mathrm dy+F_Y(0)$$
Now, taking the derivative with respect to $z$,
$$f_{X/Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|y|f_Y(y)f_x(zy).$$
Thus, in our case,
$$f_{X/Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |y|f_X(zy)f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|y|\exp\left(-\frac{y^2(1+z^2)}2\right)\mathrm{d}y=\frac1{2\pi(1+z^2)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|t|\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t=\frac1{\pi(1+z^2)}\int_{0}^\infty t\exp(-t^2/2)\mathrm d t=\frac1{\pi(1+z^2)}[-\exp(-t^2/2)]_0^\infty=\frac1{\pi(1+z^2)}$$
